# Cppcheck : mismatchAllocDealloc error

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, cppcheck

I have checked my program with cppcheck, and it complains about some mismatchAllocDealloc errors. I don't really understand what I have done wrong. What's the meaning of this error ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am a Cppcheck author.

Example code:

```
p1 = malloc(10);
delete p1;  // <- should use "free(p1)"

p2 = new char[10];
free(p2);   // <- should use "delete[] p2"
```

etc

Comment: Thank you. By the way, is there somewhere error codes are explained in detail, with some example to solve them ?

Comment: We have talked about adding it. It would be nice have. But nobody has done the all the job. you have some samples here: https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/tree/master/samples , feel free to contribute more samples